# What are the difference between an active open and a passive open in a TCP socket?

Tags: networking

I am studying basics of networking and get confused about it. Can any one explain difference between the two in simple words.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

- A passive open is the creation of a listening socket, to accept incoming connections. It uses `socket(), bind(), listen(),` followed by an `accept()` loop.
- An active open is the creation of a connection to a listening port by a client. It uses `socket()` and `connect()`.

Answer (score 7):

at least in simple terms:
passive open is on the SERVICE (server or listener) side
active is the CLIENT (source or initiat

Comment: Do you ever plan to finish this answer?

Comment: @RussellReed I don't see how you are able to read the OP's mind, and in any case your edit is ungrammatical.